# Returning indexes of intersected lists with Python

Tags: python, intersection

I have two lists:

```
1. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f']
2. ['c', 'd']
```

and I'd like to get indexes of the intersection a, b:

```
3. [[2, 3], [5, 6]]
```

How would you do that with Python?

Also these inputs:

```
1. ['263', '9', '470', '370', '576', '770', '800', '203', '62', '370', '576', '370', '25', '770', '484', '61', '914', '301', '550', '770', '484', '1276', '108']
2. ['62', '370', '576']
```

should give:

```
3. [[8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Don't understand the output yet. You want pairs of indexes of the original two lists? But your output isn't right in that case.

Comment: @martijnn2008: Looks right to me; `['c', 'd']` is found at indices 2 and 3, and at indices 5 and 6.

Comment: So you only use the indexes of the first list and the second one is ignored?

Comment: Yes, the second is ignored in that sense. The second is used to find out indexes from the first list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f']
>>> l2 = ['c', 'd']
>>> [range(i,i+len(l2)) for i in xrange(len(l1)-len(l2)+1) if l2 == l1[i:i+len(l2)]]
[[2, 3], [5, 6]]
>>>
```

Comment: This seems alright, thanks. For example: l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f'], l2 = ['d'] => [[3], [6]] which is right on what I'm waiting for output.

Comment: 10000 loops, best of 3: 7.56 µs per loop

Answer (score 1):

For your given example this will work

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f']
>>> y = ['c', 'd']
>>> z = [[i for i, xi in enumerate(x) if xi == yi] for yi in y]
>>> z
[[2, 5], [3, 6]]
>>> zip(*z)
[(2, 3), (5, 6)]
```

It makes uses of the enumerate function to get the indices of `x` along with the values and then transposes the result using `zip(*z)`. You can convert from tuples to lists afterward.

Edit: transposed result.

Comment: Output must be: [[2, 3], [5, 6]]. It is important to find out indexes of the input in that order.

Comment: %%timeit: 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.65 µs per loop

Comment: I'd like to accept this because of efficiency and clarity of code, but it is giving wrong answer with my second example. Can you see why?

Comment: It looks like this is a different algorithm to the one you require. It gives the individual intersection of each list element then transposes them. If any of the individual intersections don't match a full intersection the transpose breaks.

From your second example it looks like you are looking for an algorithm that returns the indices of sublists inside a list. For that I think I would have done the same as devnull.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little too much code, but it works.

```
def indexes(list, element):
    c = 0
    output = []
    for e in list:
        if e == element:
            output.append(c)
        c += 1
    return output

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
b = ['a', 'd']
output = []
for el in b:
    output.append(indexes(a, el))

print(output)
```

Comment: This is something I was trying, but knew that 
there is more pythonic way to do it. However it doesn't give right answer with this for example: a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f'], b = ['b', 'c', 'd'] which should be: [[1, 2, 3]]